# ProGuard Obufscation and Shadow Dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, proguard

I am trying to use ProGuard to obfuscate my code, and then using the outputted code, use Shadow to add the needed dependencies into the JAR.

Currently, I am simply getting a `-obf` JAR and a `-all` JAR. What I need is a `-all` JAR with obfuscated code.

```
import proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath group: 'net.sf.proguard', name: 'proguard-gradle', version: '5.3.1'
    classpath group: 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins', name: 'shadow', version: '1.2.4'
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

jar {
  manifest { attributes("Main-Class": "com.skcraft.launcher.Launcher") }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2'
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.0'
  compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.2'
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
  compile 'com.beust:jcommander:1.32'
  compile 'com.miglayout:miglayout:3.7.4'
  compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  compile files ('libs/javax-crypto.jar')
}

processResources {
  filesMatching('**/*.properties') {
    filter {
      it.replace('${project.version}', project.version)
    }
  }
}

task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
  configuration '../proguard.txt'

  injars jar
  outjars "${buildDir}/libs/launcher-${version}-obf.jar"

  libraryjars files(configurations.compile.collect())
}

shadowJar {
  dependencies {
    exclude(dependency('org.projectlombok:lombok'))
  }
}

build.dependsOn(obfuscate)
build.dependsOn(shadowJar)

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = "3.1" }
```

Any ideas? One idea I did come up with using the `shadowJar` and then obfuscate that, however I need to configure my `proguard.txt` to only obfuscate my code. I attempted to do this below, but it still tried to obfuscate all the packages, throwing errors:

```
# Include java runtime classes
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar

# Output a source map file
-printmapping proguard.map

# Keep filenames and line numbers
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable

# Disable certain proguard optimizations which remove stackframes (same as Android defaults)
-optimizations !method/inlining/*

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class !com.skcraft.** { *; }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, figured I'd post the solution here.

Using the Shadow task, I was able to specify the file I wanted it to read from:

```
shadowJar {
 from file("${buildDir}/libs/launcher-${version}-obf.jar")
 dependencies {
   exclude(dependency('org.projectlombok:lombok'))
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: id did not work for me. I initially made an obfuscated thin jar and passed that as parameter in shadow jar. But the jar produced did not have any obfuscated code.
did you check if it worked for you by decompiling the fat jar?

Comment: @wizneel Yes, "from" seems to do nothing, did you found a solution?

Comment: This will only run your own class files through proguard. If you want to obfuscate / optimize everything, you'll have to switch the order and use the shadowJar as injar for proguard.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to remove the following rule:

```
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

This rule implicitly will keep everything except your own code:

```
-keep class !com.skcraft.** { *; }
```

It uses an exclusion pattern (`!`) that ends the rule, which means that everything else that does not match the pattern is kept.

Comment: Did not work, it still tried to modify all the files, throwing errors.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. You have the following in your obfuscate task:   `libraryjars files(configurations.compile.collect())`, while it should be changed to injars if you want to collect all dependencies into a single uber jar with ProGuard. Additionally, this injars has to be above the outjars to work correctly.

Comment: You are still misunderstanding. I already am able to pass in a JAR with all the dependencies in it, I need to modify my proguard configuration so it completely ignores everything except my code - in the package `com.skcraft`